# Calculating width of a floating element

Tags: javascript

you can see for example in wikipedia here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States
The second pargraph starting with "At 3.79 million square miles".
If you check the width of this pharagraph it will give you the full width including the width of the floating right element '.infobox'
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/38/54351130.jpg/

But I need to get the Exact width of the pharagraph displayed to the user (which is the pharagraph width - the infobox etc').
However assuming I have no idea that there is a floating element and I want javascript to calculate the exact displayed width of the contect.
Thank you.

Edit:
Here is an example to the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/guy_l/sj3Zp/2/
Scrolling through the DOM I get the same results however the calculated witdh is different.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your scenario with a jQuery solution which works fine:

```
<script>

    // with all margins and paddings
    var w1  = $('.c_2').outerWidth(true);
    var w2  = $('.c_3').width();

    alert ('Calculated width: ' + w2 + ' - ' + w1 + ' = ' + ( w2-w1) );

</script>

<style>

    .c_1 {
        border:         1px solid red;
    }

    .c_2 {
        float:          right;
        width:          22em;
        height:         200px;
        margin:         0px 20px;
        padding:        0px 20px;
        border:         1p solid orange;
    }

    .c_3 {
        border:         1px solid blue;
    }

</style>

<div class="c_1">

    <div class="c_2">
        Infopanel
    </div>

    <p>
        Some paragraph
    </p>
    <p class="c_3">
        The interesting paragraph
    </p>

</div>
```

Comment: this would work if I knew each time there is a floating div inside my content. My problem is that I don't know. I just loop through the paragraphs and locate their width using $().width() etc' which gives me the width of the paragraph but not the width displayed to the user (since we have a floating element breaking the width of the computed style).

Comment: If you're not sure, whether, there are floating elements, you could select the parent, choose all elements, that have a floating, calculate their positions within the parent, look up, whether the paragraph is affected by the position of the floating elements and than subtract it from the paragraph's width. This could get very tricky, if you look up "**The coastal plain of the Atlantic seaboard gives way further inland**" in your link, you also see, that this paragraph has actually 2 widths as it is at the end of the floating container.

Comment: I guess this is the only solution then. thank you.  Strange that we can't get the actually "computed" width of the paragraph.

Comment: If you find another one, I would also be highly interested in the solution. :)